# kpcli bash script to automate entries

Tags: bash, expect

I am trying to create a bash script which uses kpcli in order to automate entries into a kdbx file. While searching over here I found out that you 
could use expect and send, however this does not seem to be working for me.

```
set timeout 10
spawn kpcli
match_max 100000000
expect  "kpcli:/>"
send    "open global.kdbx\n"
expect  "Please provide the master password:"
send    "mypassword"
expect  "kpcli:/>"
send    "cd Websites/"

while IFS=" " read -r domainname username password

do

expect  "kpcli:/Websites>"
send    "new "$domainname""
expect  "Username:"
send    ""$username""
expect  "Password:"
send    ""$password""
expect  "Retype to verify: "
send    "$password"
expect  "URL:"
send    ""$domainname""
expect  "Tags:" 
send    "\n"
expect  "Strings: (a)dd/(e)dit/(d)elete/(c)ancel/(F)inish?"
send     "F"
send     "\n"
expect "Database was modified. Do you want to save it now? [y/N]: "
send   "y"
send   "y"

done < sites.txt
```

Is this the way to do it or is there a better way?

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0), for SE to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to delete your post, there should be a "delete" button just below the tags, on the left. You may need to use a browser, rather than the mobile app.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you're mixing expect and bash syntax. It's possible to mix the two, but it's cleaner to just pick one. Here's your code in expect:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set timeout 10
match_max 100000000

spawn kpcli

expect  "kpcli:/>"
send    "open global.kdbx\r"
expect  "Please provide the master password:"
send -- "mypassword\r"
expect  "kpcli:/>"
send    "cd Websites/\r"

set filehandle [open sites.txt r]
while {[gets $filehandle line] != -1} {
    lassign [split $line] domainname username password

    expect  "kpcli:/Websites>"
    send    "new $domainname\r"
    expect  "Username:"
    send -- "$username\r"
    expect  "Password:"
    send -- "$password\r"
    expect  "Retype to verify: "
    send -- "$password\r"
    expect  "URL:"
    send -- "$domainname\r"
    expect  "Tags:" 
    send    "\r"
    expect  "Strings: (a)dd/(e)dit/(d)elete/(c)ancel/(F)inish?"
    send    "F\r"
    expect  "Database was modified. Do you want to save it now? [y/N]: "
    send    "y\r"
}
close $filehandle
```

I made some assumptions about how often you have to hit Enter (`\r`)